# Is this still in use in modern English?

Tags: present-participles, discourse-context

Please read the sentence below, Is it possible in modern English or is it **common** nowdays?

> *He smiled at her again and, **not smiling**, she looked curiously at her husband.*

From: E.Hemingway - The short happy life of Francis Macomber

I think it should be something like this:

*He smiled at her again and, **while she wasn't smiling**, she looked curiously at her husband.*

Comment: I read the two versions, and found that the first version is much better. The second version sounds a little awkward, and it made me think that the wife wasn't smiling the whole time. The original version doesn't force me to think that way, and emphasize more on her action (looking curiously at her husband, without smiling). But the difference is very little.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hemingway's usage is ordinary, and deliberate.

Your rewrite would mislead the reader. In that position it would initially lead her to understand *while* in the sense *although*—“even though Mrs. Macomber did not smile at Wilson she *did* look curiously at her husband. If the reader succeeded in correcting this original misreading she would next understand there to be a distinct timespan during which Mrs. Macomber was not smiling, she would then backtrack through the passage for some indication of when this obviously significant episode of non-smiling began.

Hemingway’s meaning is much simpler: Mrs. Macomber pointedly does not return Wilson’s smile. Instead, she looks ‘curiously’ at her husband, presumably to see how he he takes what Wilson has said. A moment later she reverses this: “Wilson looked over at her without smiling and now she smiled at him.”

Throughout this scene, Mrs. Macomber looks back and forth between the two men, like a spectator at a tennis match; she repeatedly subverts the careful banality of the conversation, trying to turn it into a contest between the two men, hoping that Wilson will humiliate her husband. Her looks and smiles—and non-smiles—articulate the subtext which the men carefully eliminate from the dialogue.

Comment: This IS a garden path sentence though even if it doesn't misguide the reader for very long (I habitually attach the "not smiling" to "he", and only upon encountering "she" re-attach it where the author intended.)

Comment: Thank you StoneyB for your elaborate answer. It is very instructive.

Comment: Please forgive me for abusing your kindnesses.I assume that you have read this story. If yes, Would you please clarify the subject of "I rather liked him too"? Is he Wilson? Or it is the narrator!!? if it's Wilson then why is he saying "too"?

Comment: @SF. Hmm ... I had not considered that reading. I mark the first comma disjunction and the *she* pretty much as one chunk; that may be because I've known the story for fifty years. "... and she, not smiling, looked .." would forestall that ambiguity - but then that's not really Hemingway's cadence, is it?

Comment: @GATA It's Wilson. Hemingway does not speak in his own person in this work. The *too* is contrastive, expressing Wilson's regret that FM has not only proved a coward, he has **also** disappointed Wilson's expectations.

Comment: @StoneyB Thank you very much. I was really confused.